# Why does my SQL query not work?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I wrote a query to retrieve some data from SQL Server:

```
 declare @Orig varchar(10);
 set @Orig = 205801;

 declare @ServiceCode varchar(10);
 set @ServiceCode = 'PEJ';

 SELECT  
     ContentId, COALESCE(Content, [Text]) as Content, COUNT(*) as [count]
 FROM 
     [SendArchive_92].[dbo].[9210]
 INNER JOIN
     [VSServices].[dbo].[ServiceContents] ON [VSServices].[dbo].[ServiceContents].[Id] =[SendArchive_92].[dbo].[9210].[ContentId]
 WHERE 
     [SendArchive_92].[dbo].[9210].Orig = @Orig 
     AND [SendArchive_92].[dbo].[9210].ServiceCode = @ServiceCode 
 GROUP BY 
     [VSServices].[dbo].[ServiceContents].[Text], [SendArchive_92].[dbo].[9210].ContentId
```

but I get an error

> Column 'SendArchive_92.dbo.9210.Content' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause`

and when I remove `COALESCE` in query it works properly, what is the problem?

Comment: Error is clear enough - you don't have `CONTENT` in the `GROUP BY` clause, but you do have `TEXT` there.

Answer (score 1):

First, the query is easier to write and read with table aliases:

```
SELECT t9.ContentId, COALESCE(t9.Content, sc.[Text]) as Content, COUNT(*)as [count]
FROM [SendArchive_92].[dbo].[9210] t9 inner join
     [VSServices].[dbo].[ServiceContents] s
     on sc.[Id] = t9.[ContentId]
where t9.Orig = @Orig and sc = @ServiceCode 
group by sc.[Text], t9.ContentId;
```

The issue is that `ContentId`, but not `Content` is in the `group by` clause.

Comment: Any particular reason for the downvote?  Or is it just malicious?